# usbtiny not working with avrdude

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, atmel, avrdude

I recently bought a USBtiny ISP programmer from gikfun on eBay. It is labeled Deek Robot v20 on the PCB. It was cheap. 
Using avrdude I am unable to communicate with my atmega328p micro-controller. The drivers for USBtiny are loaded correctly.

I'm getting the error

```
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
...
```

The 6 pin IDC connector from the USBtinyto atmega328p is wired up like this:

`IDC pin      atmega328p
1            18 (MISO)
2             7 (Vcc)
3            19 (SCK)
4            17 (MOSI)
5             1 (RESET)
6             8 (GND)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the IDC cable that came with the USBtiny is made incorrectly. The connector on one end is on backwards, so after taking that into consideration I was able to get it to work.